# Java Jackson JSON without property name

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I have this JSON example

> { "name": "custom_text" }

My Object look like

`public class NameObj {
    private String name;
}`

And with readValue() method from Jackson can deserialized my json into NameObj.

The real problem is when i don't have "name"

> { [ "custom_text" ] }

How create object in this case? And deserialization is same?

Comment: `[ "custom_text" ]` is a JSON array, `{ [ "custom_text" ] }` isn't valid JSON (the array should be the value of a field, e.g. `{ "names" : [ "custom_text" ] }`)

Comment: ok. and how to deal with "custom_text ? as an Array[] or List<String> names ?

Comment: In the example { "names" : [ "custom_text" ] } it does not really matter if you represent the [ "custom_text" ] as list or array but if you choose the latter, it would rather be String[] instead of Array[]. Also mind the type erasure if you choose List<String>. Then you have to use e.g. [TypeReference](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference) helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the example { "names" : [ "custom_text" ] } it does not really
>   matter if you represent the [ "custom_text" ] as list or array but if
>   you choose the latter, it would rather be String[] instead of Array[].
>   Also mind the type erasure if you choose List String . Then you have
>   to use e.g. TypeReference helpers.

Answer by mle

List String  work for me. Thank you mle